# Using the LINQ to SQL OnLoaded() method results in an empty sequence for my aggregate root?

Tags: c#

I can't find much information on the LINQ to SQL OnLoaded() partial method used with entity types. I'm running into an issue and it must be due to my lack of understanding how the method is supposed to be used or some other oversight on my part.

I have an aggregate root, Account, which has a collection of entities, of type Balance, called BalanceHistory. I have defined a property in the class called CurrentBalance which is not mapped to any column in my source table. Instead, I use OnLoaded to set its value as the most recent entry from the BalanceHistory collection.

```
partial void OnLoaded()
{
    var balance = this.BalanceHistory
                      .OrderByDescending(b => b.Datestamp)
                      .First();
    this.CurrentBalance = balance.Value;
}
```

The BalanceHistory collection is loaded with the Account entity, i.e. it is not lazy loaded. Here are the load options for my DataContext class.

```
public AccountRepository()
{
    var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    this._dataContext = new DbDataContext(connection);
    var options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Account>(a => a.BalanceHistory);
    this._dataContext.LoadOptions = options;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that whenever I try to retrieve Account objects from my DataContext class, I get an InvalidOperationException saying "Sequence contains no elements." However, if I use the debugger and look through the DataContext object, I can see that only the Account objects are missing. All of the Balance objects in the BalanceHistory collection are there. However, if I comment out the OnLoaded method the set of Accounts is retrieved without error (but of course, the CurrentBalance property is not populated).

So I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions? Besides figuring out what I'm doing wrong, I'd also be interested in hearing any ideas for a better implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably CurrentBalance is a property added in a partial class implementation.  In that case, I would calculate it the first time that the property is invoked rather than populating it when the parent object is loaded.

```
private decimal? currentBalance;
public decimal CurrentBalance
{
    get
    {
         if (!this.currentBalance.HasValue)
         {
              var balance = this.BalanceHistory
                                .OrderByDescending(b => b.Datestamp)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
              this.currentBalance = balance == null ? 0M : balance.Value;
         }
         return this.currentBalance.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I do like your approach better.